# opencv is not detected in Jupyter notebook, although it is installed in system

Tags: python, opencv, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda

When i try to import 'cv2' in a jupyter notebook, i got the error message:

> No module named 'cv2'

I already installed it with pip. as shown in the screenshot
[opencv version in pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVK5h.png)
when i try to install it with conda, it does not install as shown in the screenshot
[failed to install 'opencv' with 'conda'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBY4a.png)

Comment: Please re instantized the notebook (Reload) if you have installed the cv2 after opening current notebook.

Comment: Please don't post errors or console output as screenshots. Always copy/paste it into your question

Answer (score 0):

1 - Try this first

```
pip install opencv-python
```

2- Add path conda then try this

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```